# Chamada de método dentro da JSP

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, servlet

Bom dia pessoal!
Estava com problemas para formatar datas na jsp, porém com a ajuda dos amigos daqui, consegui resolver.

O problema é que acho que acho que meu código ficou longe das boas práticas no JSP, tive que programar dentro da página, mas amigos me falaram que eu podia chamar o método getInicioFormatado() direto que resolveria, porém não consegui... estou deixando as classes aqui embaixo, retirei a maior parte que achei desnecessária, porém se alguém precisar de algo é só falar.

Obs.: para persistência estou usando hibernate.

Obrigado pela ajuda pessoal!

Classe do Fornecedor.

```
/* imports e anotations desnecessários para o exemplo, foram omitidos.

public class Fornecedor extends Pessoa{

@Column
private Integer codigo;
@Column
private String pessoaContato;
@Column
private String cnpj;
@Column
private Date inicioAtividades;

    /* construtores, get and seters desnecessários para o exemplo, foram omitidos.

public  Date getInicioAtividades()  {


    return inicioAtividades;
}
public void setInicioAtividades( java.util.Date inicioAtividades) {
    this.inicioAtividades = (Date) inicioAtividades;
}


public String getInicioFormatado() { 
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String data = sdf.format(inicioAtividades);
    return  data;
    }
```

Servlet Controle Fornecedor

```
protected void buscar(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

try{
List<Fornecedor> listaFornecedores = new FornecedorDao().listarFornecedores();

    request.setAttribute("listaFornecedores", listaFornecedores);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("cadFornecedores.jsp").forward(request, response);

}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Fornecedor Dao

```
public List<Fornecedor> listarFornecedores() {
    session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    List<Fornecedor> listaFornecedores = new ArrayList<Fornecedor>();
    query = session.createQuery("FROM Fornecedor");

    listaFornecedores = query.list();
    session.close();
    return listaFornecedores;   
    }
```

Cadastro de fornecedores JSP (onde dei muita volta)

```
<c:if test="${fn:length(listaFornecedores) > 0 }">

    <br>
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <tr>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Código</th>
            <th>Telefone</th>
            <th>Endereço</th>
            <th>Nº</th>
            <th>Cep</th>
            <th>Bairro</th>
            <th>Cidade</th>
            <th>Estado</th>
            <th>E-mail</th>
            <th>Nome do Contato</th>
            <th>CNPJ</th>
            <th>Início das Atividades</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        <% List<Fornecedor> listaFornecedores = new FornecedorDao().listarFornecedores();
            Integer i = 0;
            Fornecedor f = new Fornecedor();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        %> 


        <c:forEach items="${listaFornecedores }" var="forn">


            <tr>
                <td id="nome${forn.id}">${forn.nome }</td>
                <td id="codigo${forn.id}">${forn.codigo }</td>
                <td id="telefone${forn.id}">${forn.telefone }</td>
                <td id="endereco${forn.id}">${forn.endereco }</td>
                <td id="numero${forn.id}">${forn.numeroDoEndereco }</td>
                <td id="cep${forn.id}">${forn.cep }</td>
                <td id="bairro${forn.id}">${forn.bairro }</td>
                <td id="cidade${forn.id}">${forn.cidade }</td>
                <td id="estado${forn.id}">${forn.estado }</td>
                <td id="email${forn.id}">${forn.email }</td>
                <td id="nomecontato${forn.id}">${forn.pessoaContato }</td>
                <td id="cnpj${forn.id}">${forn.cnpj }</td>
                <td id="inicioAtividades${forn.id}">


                <% 
                f.setid(listaFornecedores.get(i).getid());
                f.setInicioAtividades(listaFornecedores.get(i).getInicioAtividades());  
                    String data =  sdf.format(f.getInicioAtividades());
                out.print(data);
                    //System.out.println(f.getInicioFormatado());
                    i=i+1;

                %>
                                    </td>
                                <td><a href="#alterarFornecedor"
                                    class="btn btn-xs btn-info alterarFornecedor"
                                    data-togle="modal" data-id = "${forn.id }">Alterar</a> <a
                                    href="excluirForn.html?id=${forn.id }"
                                    class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">Remover</a></td>
                            </tr>


                        </c:forEach>
                    </table>
                </c:if>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Algumas observações:**

Como você está adicionando sua lista de fornecedores como um `àttribute` a sua `request` nesse trecho:

```
request.setAttribute("listaFornecedores", listaFornecedores);
```

O seguinte trecho de código no seu JSP se torna desnecessário:

```
<% List<Fornecedor> listaFornecedores = new FornecedorDao().listarFornecedores();
        Integer i = 0;
        Fornecedor f = new Fornecedor();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
%>
```

Caso você tivesse mencionado no outro tópico que o objetivo de ter uma `Date` formatada era para exibi-la no seu JSP, nós podíamos ter te instruído a utilizar a taglib `fmt` e formatá-la dentro do próprio JSP. Dessa forma. Exemplo:

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${fornecedor.inicioAtividades}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
```

Seu código ficaria assim:

Seu Servlet:

```
protected void buscar(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    try{
        List<Fornecedor> listaFornecedores = new FornecedorDao().listarFornecedores();

        request.setAttribute("listaFornecedores", listaFornecedores);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("cadFornecedores.jsp").forward(request, response);

    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Seu JSP:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Lista de Fornecedores</title>

    <!-- Seu css, javascript, etc -->

</head>
<body>

    <!-- O resto do conteúdo da sua página -->

    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>Código</th>
                <th>Telefone</th>
                <th>Endereço</th>
                <th>Nº</th>
                <th>Cep</th>
                <th>Bairro</th>
                <th>Cidade</th>
                <th>Estado</th>
                <th>E-mail</th>
                <th>Nome do Contato</th>
                <th>CNPJ</th>
                <th>Início das Atividades</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <c:forEach var="fornecedor" items="${listaFornecedores}">
                <tr>
                    <td id="nome${fornecedor.id}">${fornecedor.nome}</td>
                    <td id="codigo${fornecedor.id}">${fornecedor.codigo}</td>
                    <td id="telefone${fornecedor.id}">${fornecedor.telefone}</td>
                    <td id="endereco${fornecedor.id}">${fornecedor.endereco}</td>
                    <td id="numero${fornecedor.id}">${fornecedor.numeroDoEndereco }</td>
                    <td id="cep${fornecedor.id}">${fornecedor.cep}</td>
                    <td id="bairro${fornecedor.id}">${fornecedor.bairro}</td>
                    <td id="cidade${fornecedor.id}">${fornecedor.cidade}</td>
                    <td id="estado${fornecedor.id}">${fornecedor.estado}</td>
                    <td id="email${fornecedor.id}">${fornecedor.email}</td>
                    <td id="nomecontato${fornecedor.id}">${fornecedor.pessoaContato}</td>
                    <td id="cnpj${fornecedor.id}">${fornecedor.cnpj}</td>
                    <td id="inicioAtividades${fornecedor.id}">
                        <fmt:formatDate value="${fornecedor.inicioAtividades}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
            <c:if test="${empty listaFornecedores}">
                <tr><td colspan="100%">Nenhum fornecedor cadastrado</td></tr>
            </c:if>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Kra, obrigado, de verdade! Respondeu até mais do que eu precisava. Funcionou perfeitamente, e ainda me deu a ideia caso não tenha fornecedor cadastrado, mostrar a mensagem com o c:if. :)